# How to see all the open folders I have currently?

Tags: macos

I have a folder icon in my icon list that opens my 'Downloads' folder.

The folder isn't visible on my screen after a while because I have other apps open and they get hidden under them.

How can I see all the folders I have currently open?  I usually just open another one and its a pain.

Comment: You said, "_I have a folder icon in my icon list that opens my 'Downloads' folder._", what exactly are you referring to when you say "_in my icon list_"? If you want to see what Finder windows you have open, you can right-click on the Finder Dock Tile in the Dock and see a list of windows, which you can click on the one you want.  Or click the Windows menu in Finder, the list of open windows is there are well.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't exactly understand what you meant by "icon list" or generally what you are asking, but i guess you mean that you have several Finder windows open, and you want to easily see all of them. You have a few ways of accomplishing this task:

1. You can use Mission Control, either by using the swipe gesture (three-finger swipe up on a trackpad or two-finger swipe up on the magic mouse) or by pressing <kbd>F3</kbd>. This will neatly organize all the current windows open in your space (aka desktop or full-screen application).
2. You can use the more specific App Exposè, which shows you all of the current windows **for a specific app**. So focus on just one of the Finder windows, and go into the App Exposè by either using the swipe gesture if you have it enabled (which is the same as the Mission Control gesture, just down instead of up), or by (I think) pressing <kbd>Function</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd>.
3. Lastly, you can see a list of all the open windows on a specific app (on your case Finder) by right-clicking (or <kbd>Control</kbd>-clicking) it's dock icon.

If you find yourself having a lot of folders open a lot of times, I REALLY recommend that you tabs instead. You can always open a new finder tab by pressing `command+tab` and you can press `command+option+tab` to toggle the tab bar.

Comment: control-click or right click on the icon doesn't show me all open finders?

Comment: @Blankman I don't understand what you are asking...

Comment: @Blankman if my answer solved your problem, please mark it as the solution :)